# How to insert one list into another list in python

Tags: python, list

here's my code:

```
d = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
a = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']
b = []
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    c = a[i].split()
    for i in d:
        b.append(c.count(i))
print(b)
```

here's the output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

but i want the desired output like this:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this achieves what you want:

```
d = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
a = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']
b = []
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    c = a[i].split()
    e = []
    for i in d:
        e.append(c.count(i))
    b.append(e)
print(b)
```

Note the addition of a local array 'e' which has the contents appended to, this is then appended to your array 'b'

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are not creating nor adding elements to a **nested list**. Here's a  way to do it adapting your code:

```
# Start by creating a nsted list the same length of a
b = [[] for _ in range(len(a))]
# [[], [], []]
# Do the same but instead appending the elements to the sublists
# in b using i as index
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    c = a[i].split()
    for j in d:
        b[i].append(c.count(j))
print(b)

# [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

---

You could also use a nested list comprehension to achieve this:

```
[[j.split().count(i) for i in d] for j in a]
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use List Comprehension:

```
d = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
a = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']

list_of_lists = [[x.split().count(y) for y in d] for x in a]

print list_of_lists
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python's list comprehension

```
d = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
a = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']
b = []
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    c = a[i].split()
    b.append([c.count(i) for i in d])
print(b) # [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spam = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
eggs = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']

print([[int(word in egg.split(' ')) for word in spam] for egg in eggs])
```

output

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go -

```
d = ['ant', 'bird', 'gecko', 'snake', 'wasp']
a = ['rabbit panda bird rabbit', 'bird gecko ant panda', 'wasp snake gecko ant']
b = []
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    c = a[i].split()
    count_list = [c.count(i) for i in d]
    b.append(count_list)
print(b)

Output - 
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other one liner option:

```
[ [ sub.count(word) for word in d ] for sub in [ string.split() for string in a ] ]
#=> [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

It states for each `word` in `d` count its occurrence in `sub`, where `sub` is a sub-list derived for each `string` in `a`.

```
[ string.split() for string in a ]
#=> [['rabbit', 'panda', 'bird', 'rabbit'], ['bird', 'gecko', 'ant', 'panda'], ['wasp', 'snake', 'gecko', 'ant']]
```